# bootstrap carousel with multiple items doesn't move 1 image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I want to implement a Bootstrap 3 carousel with multiple items on my page and it should move one image each step. I tried using a few examples that I found and every time the same problem. When I inspect element, I see 4 images in each item and then it moves the item but all the 4 images are moving together.

At the moment I use the example I found [here](http://www.bootply.com/quUFQAdYN2).

[This is](http://www.sea-gal.co.il/document/218,0,1.aspx) My page that I use the carousel in.

Please help!

I add my HTML code here

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style=" direction: ltr">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250227371376.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250229867424.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250232831481.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250234859520.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250236731556.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250238603592.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250240475628.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250242503667.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this ios the javascript i'm using:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    })

    $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the css i'm using:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25% ; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25% ; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left:  -25% ; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:-15px;background-image:none;}
```

Comment: Don't know why your page says something else then your code. I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Oke. Its not the problem with your html. Your javascript is moving the `<div class='item'>`

Change your html to this.

```
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style=" direction: ltr">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="GIVE_THIS_ANOTHER_CLASS">
                        <div class="item active col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sea-gal.co.il/sysvault/docsgalleries28/thcdp635830250227371376.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!-- YOUR OTHER DIVS WITH IMAGES UNDER THIS-->

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

The class `item active` replace them in the `col-md-3` `div`
Your javascript is moving the div's with the class `item` and is not trying to move the images inside it. So remake your javascript or replace your classes

Comment: Thank you. I know that, and if you look at the source of HTML insted of inspect element you wil see that this is what i did. that is the problem which I do not understand.

Comment: You are moving the div where the 4 div's are in instead of moving the parent divs of the images. Add some html code of your page so i can help you better

Comment: Thanx. I added the HTML in the original quastion.

Comment: I did what you wrote but it only confused the hole HTML. as far as I understand what is going on there I think that it moves the hole width of the item insted of moving 25% of it. but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Post you javascript. i will try to rebuild it

Comment: @tartash i downloaden the slider myself. I coudn't find the problem within the code. I think it is a bootstrap problem. Visit this link http://thedesignhill.com/jquery-image-and-content-sliders/ there are some good sliders on it.